# Cannot install via pip within virtualenv

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

so I tried to set up an working environment to code some stuff with python. I used this really nice website [newcoder.io](http://newcoder.io/begin/setup-your-machine/#mac-os-x) to do it the right way.
Unfortunately I came across a big problem I cannot solve by myself even after several hours of trial and error (sponsored by Google).

I installed all required packages starting from python, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper. I also changed the .bashprofile for using Terminal as stated. Then I tried to test the working environment like described in the aforementioned website [newcoder.io Test](http://newcoder.io/begin/setup-your-machine/#test-your-setup).
As I was within the working environment named "TestEnv" I tried to install django via pip. Here is the result coming from Terminal:

```
(TestEnv)username:~ username$ pip install django
-bash: /Users/username/.virtualenvs/TestEnv/bin/pip: "/Users/brokenusername: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

As you can see there seems to be something wrong with the underlying links. I have to admit, that I recently changed my account name and the name of the home directory in OS X Mavericks (see "username" and "brokenusername" within the code). Everything went fine so far. The username is now without blank spaces in the name (a different, bigger problem, but solved). But pip still seems to keep the old "brokenusername".

My **Question** is, how do I change the "brokenusername" to "username" so that pip is able to its work.

Thanks for all advices.

Here is a [sloth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2P7G.jpg) for all your efforts to help !

*Please note*: I am newbie when it comes to understand and change these kind of working environments. I tried my best to find a solution by myself. But it seems like I need some advice from the Internetz.

Comment: How about just deleting the virtualenv and creating a new one?

Comment: @tdelaney It actually worked! All my trial and errors where tested within a single environment. Now i created a new one and the pip install django command works! Thank you very much!

Comment: I'll write it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

virtualenv creates symlinks, environment variables  and other path links in places like .pth files that are invalidated when you change the base path of the env. But environments are cheap to create so (assuming you haven't placed other files in the virtualenv directory) just delete it and build it again.